# Grey folder in iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, finder

I have a grey folder on my Mac in the iCloud Drive Directory which I can't access. [image]

If I go to the iCloud Drive Website I see the folder and can easily navigate in it.

Does anyone know a solution on how to enable this folder on my machine as well?

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.macissues.com/2015/01/27/fix-inaccessible-and-grayed-out-folders-in-the-os-x-finder/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I fixed it by using the terminal. I moved all the content of the grayed out folder and to a new one.

//edit: a more detailed description on how I solved this problem:

1. with the help of the terminal I moved all the files in the strange behaving folder to a new location. Using the `mv` command. E.g. `cp ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/YOUR_BROKEN_FOLDER/* ~/Documents` (the * is for all the files).
2. Once this folder it empty you can safely remove it with the `rm -f` command. E.g. `rm -rf ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/YOUR_BROKEN_FOLDER`
3. If you want you can now recreate the folder normal in the finder and it should appear normal again.

Comment: This would be a more helpful answer if you added the specific steps by which you achieved a resolution to your problem.

Comment: @smspaulb done :)

Comment: thanks, very helpful now! Also, I can confirm it works as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Another easier way that I found is to just copy the shaded folder and paste it somewhere else and then move it back where it was original and it overwrites the shaded folder making it accessible again.

Comment: Sounds great. I can't confirm it yet because the problem does not occur anymore but it it works :) Thanks for sharing.